# Custom message in New Order Confirmation Shippin Method Magento CE

Tags: magento, email

I am trying to setup a custom message in the New Order Confirmation email for "Shipping Method" when someone selects the shipping method "Store Pickup" at checkout. In the DB the method name is called flatrate2. Here is the snippet that I was attempting to edit...

```
 if ($method) {
        foreach ($address->getAllShippingRates() as $rate) {
            if ($rate->getCode()==$method) {
                $amountPrice = $address->getQuote()->getStore()->convertPrice($rate->getPrice(), false);
                $this->_setAmount($amountPrice);
                $this->_setBaseAmount($rate->getPrice());
                if (!$method=='flatrate2'){
                $shippingDescription = $rate->getCarrierTitle() . ' - ' . $rate->getMethodTitle();}
                else{ $shippingDescription = 'Your merchandise will be ready for pickup 45 minutes after completing your order.<br/>Store Pickup is available Mon – Friday 11:30 AM – 4:30 PM';} 
                $address->setShippingDescription(trim($shippingDescription, ' -'));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

No matter which shipping method is selected I only get the message 'Your merchandise will be ready for pickup 45 minutes after completing your order.
Store Pickup is available Mon – Friday 11:30 AM – 4:30 PM'

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within that code do this:
if ($method=='your specific shipping ')
{ $shippingDescription = $rate->getCarrierTitle() . ' - ' . $rate->getMethodTitle();}

elseif($method=='your other shipping method ')
{ $shippingDescription = $rate->getCarrierTitle() . ' - ' . $rate->getMethodTitle();}

and so on.

To summarize all times your code condition if (!$method=='flatrate2'){ is failing resulting in else condition getting executed.

Comment: I actually ended up approaching this a different way. See below for my final edit. Thank you for the quick response. I used a phtml.

Comment: I am marking your answer as the correct response because it directly answers my question. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I approached this a different way. In my email template I added.

```
  {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='cms/orderemail.phtml' order=$order}}
```

Then in my orderemail.phtml I placed this snippet in it...

```
$pShipping = $this->getData('order')->getShippingDescription();
if ($pShipping == 'Store Pickup - Store Pickup') {
```

This solved my problem.